# Lookup Database record from array value and insert new key and value into array

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

I have an array, I would like to add another value to it from a database, using the [numo] value to lookup the record, here is the current array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [numo] => 667820161009
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [numo] => 667820112001
        )
```

and here is what I want to achieve:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 33
            [numo] => 667820161009
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 34
            [numo] => 667820112001
        )
```

I presume that would have to loop through the array, nesting a SELECT query and then insert a new key and value, but I have no idea where to start and have searched and searched.

Many thanks in advance for you help

Stu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess without knowing anything about your DB (or specifically the table that this data comes from) would be:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE numo = 667820112001
```

Some PHP to go along with this:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array(
        'numo' => 667820161009
    ),
    array(
        'numo' => 667820112001
    )
);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id FROM table WHERE numo = :numo');
$stmt->bindColumn('id', $id);

foreach($array as &$child) {
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':numo' => $child['numo']
    ));

    $child['id'] = ($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) ? $id : null;

    $stmt->closeCursor();
}
?>
```

However you can eliminate some queries with:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array(
        'numo' => 667820161009
    ),
    array(
        'numo' => 667820112001
    )
);

$numos = array()
foreach($array as $child) {
    $numos[] = $child['numo'];
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id FROM table WHERE numo IN ('.implode(',', $numos).')');
$array = $pdo->fetchAll();
?>
```

Comment: yer, I understand that part and yes your select query is correct, but I want to insert the id into the array as a new key and value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one SQL query to fetch all the ID values if you form an array of `numo` values.

```
$array = array( ...);

$numos = array();
foreach( $array as $entry)
{
    $numos[] = $entry['numo'];
}

$sql = 'SELECT id, numo FROM table WHERE numo IN ( ' . implode( ', ', $numos) . ' )';
$result = mysql_query( $sql);

$array = array(); // Reset the array
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result))
{
    $array[] = array(
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'numo' => $row['numo']
    );
}
```

Comment: ooooh' this looks positive, I will give that a shot, thanks Nick... very fast reply!!